# Can I store method calls in a tuple without calling the methods at runtime?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, methods, collections, tuples

This exercise is called Command Line Emailer and it comes from [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python CH 12 2nd ed.](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter12/)

> Write a program that takes an email address and string of text on the
> command line and then, using selenium, logs in to your email account
> and sends an email of the string to the provided address. (You might
> want to set up a separate email account for this program.)

While working through this exercise, I learned that the selenium method calls for finding html elements will sometimes work, but sometimes they will throw `noSuchElementException`. To work around this, I created three tuples to store the selenium method calls. Using the `selenium_exception_loop()` function (see below), I would loop through the tuple and call one method at a time. If the method throws a `noSuchElementFound` exception, the loop will wait two seconds then try again.

The issue, of course, is that the selenium method calls are executed at runtime. Is there any way to store the selenium method calls in a collection without actually executing the calls during runtime? Or do I need to take an entirely different approach here?

```
#!python3
# 04_command_line_emailer.py -- send emails from the command line
# usage: input four command line arguments:
# sys.argv[1] = email to log into
# sys.argv[2] = password
# sys.argv[3] = email body
# sys.argv[4] = recipient email address


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import sys
import re
import time


class commandLineEmailer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.gmail_method_calls = ()
        self.outlook_method_calls = ()
        self.yahoo_method_calls = (
            lambda: self.browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'signin').click(),
            lambda: self.browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').send_keys(self.return_email_info()[0]),
            lambda: self.browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'signin').click(),
            lambda: self.browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'password').send_keys(sys.argv[2]),
            lambda: self.browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'verifyPassword').click(),
            lambda: self.browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'Compose').click()
        )

    def return_email_info(self) -> tuple:
        '''
        Input sys.argv[1] into regex. sys.argv[1] contains the sending email
        address. return the username and the email client name.

        :return: tuple, username at index 0, email client name at index 1
        '''
        return re.compile("(.*)(\@)(.*)(\.)").match(sys.argv[1]).group(1), \
               re.compile("(.*)(\@)(.*)(\.)").match(sys.argv[1]).group(3)

    # open browser session and navigate to email client
    def go_to_email_client(self) -> None:
        EMAIL_CLIENTS = {
            'outlook': 'https://www.outlook.com/',
            'gmail': 'https://www.gmail.com/',
            'yahoo': 'https://yahoomail.com/'
        }
        self.browser.get(EMAIL_CLIENTS[self.return_email_info()[1]])

    def selenium_exception_loop(self, selenium_method_collection) -> None:
        '''
        :param selenium_method_collection: input collection containing selenium
         method calls to search for html elements. Wait two seconds between each
         method call. Except the NoSuchElementException error.
        :return: None
        '''
        for selenium_method_call in selenium_method_collection:
            while True:
                try:
                    time.sleep(2) # wait two seconds
                    selenium_method_call()
                    break
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    continue

    def sign_in_and_send(self) -> None:
        '''
        Retrieve the email client to log into. Call the selenium_exception_loop()
        function and pass it the email client tuple containing the selenium
        method calls
        :return None:
        '''
        if self.return_email_info()[1] == 'gmail':
            pass
        elif self.return_email_info()[1] == 'outlook':
            pass
        elif self.return_email_info()[1] == 'yahoo':
            self.selenium_exception_loop(self.yahoo_method_calls)

def main() -> None:
    command_line_emailer = commandLineEmailer()
    command_line_emailer.go_to_email_client()
    command_line_emailer.sign_in_and_send()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was gathered [from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/vlecc3/can_i_store_method_calls_inside_a_tuple_without/), but essentially, put `lambda` in front of each method call, and rewrite `selenium_method` as `selenium_method()` so that it is callable, like so:

```
yahoo_method_calls = (
    lambda: browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'signin').click(),
    lambda: browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').send_keys(self.return_email_info()[0]),
)

. . .

try:
    time.sleep(2)  # wait two seconds
    selenium_method_call()  # Call it
    break
```

Comment: there is also [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)